# Plotting a Continuous signal

Tags: matlab, plot, line, signal-processing

I am trying to exactly print a continuous signal as per image below:

[image]

Below is my code:

```
x=[0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 0 0];
n=[6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ];
subplot(2,2,2);
axis([min(n)-10,max(n)+10,min(x)-10,max(x)+10]);
plot(n,x); 
grid on;
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('x2(t)');
title('Continous Signal');
```

But the output plot figure is not the same as per expectations:

[image]

Is it that in MATLAB we cannot display continuous signal properly? If yes what changes I need to make in my code.

Why do the signal values are not connected via a straight line - it makes a curve (or slanted straight line)?

Comment: You surely mean a _discontinuous_ signal (i.e. with jumps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the [**`stairs`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) function:

```
x = [0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 0 0];
n = [-6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ];

stairs(n,x);
```

[image]

Comment: Woah... how did you get your plot to look so pretty like that?  Is this a different rendering mode?

Comment: @rayryeng First: [HG2-Update](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/hg2-update), second: "CMU Serif" as default axes font. That's it ;)

Comment: Beautiful.  I didn't know this was on Undocumented MATLAB... mind you I subscribed to the newsletter well after this post came out.  Thanks for this!  +1 for me btw.